# How to remove string and what comes after it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column with links in my table. Some links have a string like `/?source=rss&...`.

So I want to remove this string `/?source=rss` and what comes after it.

So if the link looks like this `https://website.com/?source=ress&id=123&name=john`

It should be `https://website.com`

I searched about it but only found replace and remove functions, And they won't work as the string is variable and not the same in every link.

I found this `UPDATE MyTable SET column = REPLACE(column, ' ', '') WHERE column LIKE '%%'`

The database is MYSQL and I'm using SQL queries there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substring_index()`:

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET column = SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '/?', 1)
    WHERE column LIKE '%/?%';
```